# Random IP Address Accessing my Website

Tags: http, robots.txt

I have been hosing a Flask website and a random IP address tried to access my server:

```
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:46] "GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:46] "GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:46] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:47] "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:47] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:47] "GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
70.188.129.128 - - [08/Feb/2015 21:55:48] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

It tried to see my root page, then my favicon, then some pictures that I believe are only on apache web servers off of Macs. I tried to look up online, but there wasn't anything about it. I'm worried that it may be a system that hacks into mac based web servers. Could it just be google or some other search engine? I have go an http request from an ip address that I didn't write down that was looking for a `robots.txt` file. And also another one that tried to look for a `.css` file:

```
94.102.53.195 - - [08/Feb/2015 23:01:47] "GET /back.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This pointed me towards a search engine, but a search left nothing. Why are these people trying to access random files. Should I be worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like somebody visited your Web page using their iPad or iPhone, and in addition to loading your home page, their browser tried to load various sizes and formats of favicons, including high-res ones. Seems pretty normal.

Those `apple-touch-icon`s are not "only on apache web servers off of Macs" and I'm not sure where you got that idea. They can be put on any web site that wants to provide high-res icons to iOS (iPhone/iPad) clients. See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Comment: I know that when the web sharing is enabled on mac, there are a couple pictures that say powered by mac and other things.